# p5.js let me use only one Lightsource

Tags: shader, p5.js

I saw this [sketch](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1070588) online and wanted to edit it to understand it more, as it would help me with my own project.

But to keep it short:
I added another Lightsource (*directionalLight()*) to the scene but it is not displaying. It only ever chooses the first one (+ ambient).
I am thinking it is because of the Shader but I never worked with C++ so I am pretty lost here.
For ease I add the shader code in here:

```
const vert = `
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec3 aNormal;
attribute vec4 aMaterialColor;

uniform float uTime;
uniform bool uUseLighting;

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 uNormalMatrix;

uniform int uDirectionalLightCount;
uniform vec3 uLightingDirection[5];
uniform vec3 uDirectionalDiffuseColors[5];
uniform vec3 uDirectionalSpecularColors[5];
//uniform vec3 uAmbientColor[5];

varying vec3 vDiffuseColor;

void main(void) {
  float amt = sin(uTime * aMaterialColor.r + aMaterialColor.g) * aMaterialColor.b;
  vec3 pos = aPosition + aNormal * amt * step(0.0, amt);
  vec4 viewModelPosition = uModelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0); 
  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * viewModelPosition;

  vec3 vertexNormal = normalize(uNormalMatrix * aNormal);
  vec3 lightDirection = normalize(-uLightingDirection[0]);
  float intensity = max(0.0, dot(lightDirection, vertexNormal));
  
  vDiffuseColor = uDirectionalDiffuseColors[0] * intensity;
  //vDiffuseColor += uAmbientColor[0];
}
`;

const frag = `
precision highp float;

uniform vec4 uMaterialColor;

varying vec3 vDiffuseColor;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = uMaterialColor;
  gl_FragColor.rgb *= vDiffuseColor;
}
`;
```

As you can see, I already tried some stuff, but I could not find a good explanation about what does what here, or in other shaders for that fact. I only found [this](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/contributor_docs/webgl_mode_architecture.md#light-parameters) list of variables but without explanation really.

Could someone explain?

Comment: Removed the C++ tag. This is WebGL+JavaScript...

Comment: @Botje thanks and I am sorry. Thought it was kind of right as it also recommended the tag.

Comment: The shader code you posted doesn't actually loop over the lightsources but instead only uses the first one.

Comment: @LJᛃ do you know how I can change that? I am not really well versed in this field :D